# Power series dense set of points of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Give an example of power series with  dense subset of points on a circle at which the series is convergent and dense subset of points on a circle at which it is divergent.

Could you tell me how to find it?

Comment: Dense on which set?

Comment: Dense subset of points on a circle.

Comment: You should definitely add that to your question; as it stands, the geometric series $\sum_{k \ge 0} x^k$ converges on the dense inside and diverges on the dense outside of the unit circle, and is an answer.